# How to change the logging level by user input in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I want the user to change the logging level by one input.
Here is my code to achieve this, but I know something is wrong:

```
print('Here are the log levels: ' +str(logLevelArr))
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s')
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('consoleappinfo.log')
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
logLevel = input ( 'What log level you  want to use?')

## Entry validation for logger
while logLevel.upper() not in logLevelArr:
    print("You didn't select from the options!")
    print('Here are the log levels: ' +str(logLevelArr))
    logger.error(' User selected wrong logging level!')
    logger.debug('---> Asking User for input for logLevel!')
    logLevel = input( 'What log level you  want to use?')
print('\n'+'*** Great, you selected ' +str(logLevel).upper() +' for the logging level ***')
logger.info('---> User selected: '+str(logLevel)+ ' for logging level')
if logLevel.upper() == 'CRITICAL':
    logger.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
if logLevel.upper() == 'ERROR':
    logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
if logLevel.upper() == 'INFO':
   logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
if logLevel.upper() == 'DEBUG':
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong?

Comment: even I type 'error', the logger is set to debug I think.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a typo in your formatting or if the indentation is actually wrong, but your code to set the log level is inside your while loop. If the user inputs a valid log level to start with, you'll never set the log level.

Answer (score 0):

use `logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)` to set the logging level and `logger =logging.getLogger()` to get the new logger.
Specifically:

```py
if logLevel.upper() == 'CRITICAL':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
if logLevel.upper() == 'ERROR':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.ERROR)
if logLevel.upper() == 'INFO':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
if logLevel.upper() == 'DEBUG':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger =logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

`logger.addHandler(file_handler)` is needed to achieve the same file logging behaviour.

full code:

```py
import logging
logLevelArr = ["CRITICAL","ERROR","INFO","DEBUG"]
print('Here are the log levels: ' +str(logLevelArr))
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s')
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('consoleappinfo.log')
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
logLevel = input ( 'What log level you  want to use?')

## Entry validation for logger
while logLevel.upper() not in logLevelArr:
    print("You didn't select from the options!")
    print('Here are the log levels: ' +str(logLevelArr))
    logger.error(' User selected wrong logging level!')
    logger.debug('---> Asking User for input for logLevel!')
    logLevel = input( 'What log level you  want to use?')
print('*** Great, you selected ' +logLevel.upper() +' for the logging level ***')
logger.info('---> User selected: '+logLevel+ ' for logging level')
if logLevel.upper() == 'CRITICAL':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
if logLevel.upper() == 'ERROR':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.ERROR)
if logLevel.upper() == 'INFO':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
if logLevel.upper() == 'DEBUG':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger =logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

# below are logging examples
logger.critical(f"start of logging, level chosen: {logLevel.upper()}")

logger.critical("some critical msg")
logger.error("some error msg")
logger.info("some info msg")
logger.debug("some debug msg")

logger.critical("end of logging")
```